# Can I sort a query by one column or another?

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a table wit two string column :
- `title` can be `NULL`
- `content` is required

If I use `ORDER BY title, content`. Data will be sorted first by `title`, and after by `content`.

I want to know if it's possible to sort by the two columns "at the same time".
It's not really clear (that's why I can not find an answer), so let's have an example :

```
Title  | Content 
-------|---------
NULL   | lorem
-------|---------
NULL   | ipsum
-------|---------
dolor  | test
-------|---------
sit    | test
```

Will result in :

```
Title  | Content 
-------|---------
dolor  | test
-------|---------
NULL   | ipsum
-------|---------
NULL   | lorem
-------|---------
sit    | test
```

In fact my problem is that in my view, title and content are displayed in the same column (if title is not null, it's shown, else I use content). There is a sort feature on this column and can not find a way to manage the sort correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `COALESCE` - it returns the first non-null value of its parameters

```
order by coalesce(title, content)
```